# Determine children within edge and return a list of tuple pairs

Tags: haskell

I've been studying hard and asking a lot of questions - I finally came a cross an exercise in LYAH that looked like it was easy enough but a perfect candidate for practicing.

The below program has a bunch of helper funcs in there, but the one of interest is `neighbors/3`.  It takes a `Pair` type and `Edge` number, and a `BiMorph` type. It then determines all of the children within that edge and returns it as a list of tuple pairs.

I would like a more experienced Haskeller to come in and tear it apart or to give me constructive criticism.

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative

data Pair a    = Pair a a deriving (Show, Eq)
data BiMorph a = BiMorph Func Func

type Neighbors = [(Int, Int)]
type Matrix    = [[Int]]
type Func      = (Int -> Int -> Int)

instance Functor Pair where
   fmap f (Pair a b) = Pair (f a) (f b)

instance Applicative Pair where
   pure a = Pair a a
   (Pair fa fb) <*> (Pair a b) = Pair (fa a) (fb b)

matrix :: Int -> Int -> Matrix
matrix xl yl = replicate yl $ [1..xl]

cartesianPairs :: Func -> Pair Int -> [Pair Int]
cartesianPairs f p =
    [(f <$> (Pair x y) <*> p) | x <- [1,0], y <- [0,1], (x,y) /= (0,0)]

cartesianDoubles :: Func -> Func -> Pair Int -> [Pair Int]
cartesianDoubles f g (Pair x y) = [Pair (f x 1) (g y 1), Pair (g x 1) (f y 1)]

dropP :: Pair Int -> (Int, Int)
dropP (Pair x y) = (abs x, abs y)

liftP :: (Int, Int) -> Pair Int
liftP (x, y) = Pair x y

neighbors :: Pair Int -> Int -> BiMorph Int -> Neighbors
neighbors p e (BiMorph f g) = 
    map dropP $ concat [(cartesianPairs f p), (cartesianPairs g p), (cartesianDoubles f g p)]
        >>= (\(Pair x' y') -> guard (x' <= e && y' <= e)
            >> return (Pair x' y'))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `hlint` tool on your source to help you with getting rid of redundant brackets, `$` and other minor suggestions.

In `neighbors` your using of `guard` in list monad can be changed to `filter` function:

```
neighbors :: Pair Int -> Int -> BiMorph Int -> Neighbors
neighbors p e (BiMorph f g) = map dropP $ filter ff $ concat [cartesianPairs f p, cartesianPairs g p, cartesianDoubles f g p] where
    ff (Pair x' y') = x' <= e && y' <= e
```

You can also hardcode the list into `cartesianPairs` as it's short:

```
cartesianPairs :: Func -> Pair Int -> [Pair Int]
cartesianPairs f p =
    [f <$> Pair x y <*> p | (x, y) <- [(1,0), (0,1), (1,1)]]
```

You can even use pairs directly:

```
cartesianPairs :: Func -> Pair Int -> [Pair Int]
cartesianPairs f p =
    [f <$> pair <*> p | pair <- [Pair 1 0, Pair 0 1, Pair 1 1]]
```

I also have an impression that `cartesianPairs` can be further simplified but I couldn't find anything that has clear meaning. Here are two attempts:

```
cartesianPairs f p =
     (<*> p) <$> (fmap . fmap) f [Pair 1 0, Pair 0 1, Pair 1 1]

cartesianPairs f p =
     (<*> p) . fmap f <$> [Pair 1 0, Pair 0 1, Pair 1 1]
```

`cartesianDoubles` can be shrinked the same way if you want:

```
cartesianDoubles f g (Pair x y) = [Pair (ff x) (gg y), Pair (gg x) (ff y)] where
    ff x = f x 1
    gg x = g x 1

cartesianDoubles f g p = [Pair ff gg <*> p, Pair gg ff <*> p] where
    ff x = f x 1
    gg x = g x 1

cartesianDoubles f g p = (<*> p) <$> [Pair ff gg, Pair gg ff] where
    ff x = f x 1
    gg x = g x 1
```

Yet another improvement. You can notice that there are versions of `cartesianDoubles` and `cartesianPairs` sharing the same `(<*> p) <$>` part:

```
cartesianPairs f p =
    (<*> p) <$> (fmap . fmap) f [Pair 1 0, Pair 0 1, Pair 1 1]

cartesianDoubles f g p = (<*> p) <$> [Pair ff gg, Pair gg ff] where
    ff x = f x 1
    gg x = g x 1
```

Then notice that `<$>` in `(<*> p) <$>` is for `Functor []` instance, so it's just plain `map`, and `map has a property of commuting with`concat`:`map f . concat == concat . map f`.

So you can move the common fragment out:

```
cartesianPairs f p =
    (fmap . fmap) f [Pair 1 0, Pair 0 1, Pair 1 1]

cartesianDoubles f g p = [Pair ff gg, Pair gg ff] where
    ff x = f x 1
    gg x = g x 1

neighbors :: Pair Int -> Int -> BiMorph Int -> Neighbors
neighbors p e (BiMorph f g) = map dropP $ filter ff $ map (<*> p) $ concat [cartesianPairs f p, cartesianPairs g p, cartesianDoubles f g p] where
    ff (Pair x' y') = x' <= e && y' <= e
```

Now `p` argument is not used:

```
cartesianPairs f =
    (fmap . fmap) f [Pair 1 0, Pair 0 1, Pair 1 1]

cartesianDoubles f g = [Pair ff gg, Pair gg ff] where
    ff x = f x 1
    gg x = g x 1

neighbors :: Pair Int -> Int -> BiMorph Int -> Neighbors
neighbors p e (BiMorph f g) = map dropP $ filter ff $ map (<*> p) $ concat [cartesianPairs f, cartesianPairs g, cartesianDoubles f g] where
    ff (Pair x' y') = x' <= e && y' <= e
```

If you want, you can convert `neighbors` to use list comprehensions:

```
neighbors :: Pair Int -> Int -> BiMorph Int -> Neighbors
neighbors p e (BiMorph f g) = 
    [ dropP xx 
    | x <- concat [cartesianPairs f, cartesianPairs g, cartesianDoubles f g]
    , let xx @ (Pair x' y') = x <*> p
    , x' <= e && y' <= e ]
```

Or even

```
neighbors :: Pair Int -> Int -> BiMorph Int -> Neighbors
neighbors p e (BiMorph f g) = 
    [ dropP xx 
    | xx @ (Pair x' y') <- (<*> p) <$> 
        concat [cartesianPairs f, cartesianPairs g, cartesianDoubles f g] 
    , x' <= e && y' <= e ]
```

But I find it less clear.

Comment: I spent some time going through this - thank you for taking the time again to go through my program. Is this generally how you program in Haskell yourself? Do you write out the general idea (as I did) then iteratively improve the functions till you find some common patterns, then generalize it? Or is this a process that happens somewhat...intuitively...for you and this was just an externalized version of what you do in your head now?

Comment: For old code it's like simplifying expressions in high school algebra. I still even don't know what your program is about. For new code the initial idea becomes better over time. At first I barely could write code without type errors, then I learned to refactor recursion into folds, then I learned to recognize folds before I write recursion, then recognision of `.` and monadic compositions became intuitive.